# How do I use LINQ's LIKE function for invalid character validation?

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq, t-sql

I'm trying to write a text validation function that uses an `ErrorProvider` to warn about bad characters instead of waiting for my SQL database to reject a command.  I know all about parameterized queries, but that doesn't help me use the `ErrorProvider`.

I found this article that has a great illegal character function in TSQL: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1430e80f-38ac-4270-b2b3-978215a534d5/most-efficient-way-checking-for-an-invalid-character-in-a-database-field?forum=transactsql

Here's the code that I'd like to write in LINQ, but I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it:

```
create table #t(s varchar(100))
insert into #t values ('This is a test!')
insert into #t values ('This is a test')
select *
from #t
where s like '%[^0-9a-zA-Z_:;<=>? ]%'
drop table #t
```

Here's my attempt to get this into LINQ to Objects but something's not working:

```
Private Sub TextBox_TextValidation(ByVal sender As TextBox, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) _
    Handles TextBox_FirstName.Validating
    'use TSQL to find illegal characters
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    dt.Columns.Add("Text")
    dt.Rows.Add(TextBox_FirstName.Text)

    Dim myQuery = From row In dt.AsEnumerable
        Where row.Item("Text") Like "%[^0-9a-zA-Z_:;<=>? ]%"
        Select row

    'I'll pretty this up later, just get the info from the query for now
    For Each x In myQuery
        If x.Item("Text") <> "" Then
            ErrorProvider1.SetError(TextBox_FirstName, "You Must Use Alpha Numeric Characters")
        Else
            ErrorProvider1.Clear()
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I'm getting an empty response for the query whether I put all "legal" characters in the textBox or not.
VS2012, VB.NET

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're overthinking things a bit.  You could do this with a Regular Expression - your current code seems to be attempting to do T-SQL in VB.NET.  LINQ is not SQL (though there are similarities).

I would scrap the whole `DataTable` and LINQ approach and do something like this:

```
Private Sub TextBox_TextValidation(ByVal sender As TextBox, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) _
Handles TextBox_FirstName.Validating

    If (Regex.IsMatch(TextBox_FirstName.Text, "[^0-9a-zA-Z_:;<=>?\s]")) Then
        ErrorProvider1.SetError(TextBox_FirstName, "You Must Use Alpha Numeric Characters")
    Else
        ErrorProvider1.Clear()
    End If
End Sub
```

You'll need to add `Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions` to your code, and note that I used `\s` instead of  for the space.

Comment: Didn't know I could use the same string in that feature.  Thank you!

Comment: How do I add the dash `"[-]"` character to the same match string?

Comment: You need to escape the `-` by adding a backslash in front of it: `\-`.